# UITableView not display text on devices

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, datasource

I develop application contains UITableView (not Controller) and it was added programmatically. I didn't use any nib file. and found out that in simulator work fine but's when I build on device Table shown up but didn't see any text on it.
Datasource and delegate is already connected.

here some code

```
if (kPortrait) {
        optionTV = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(568, 75, 200, 44 * [optionArray count]) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    } else {
        optionTV = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(824, 75, 200, 44 * [optionArray count]) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    }
    [optionTV setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
    [optionTV setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
    [optionTV setDataSource:self];
    [optionTV setDelegate:self];
    optionTV.alpha = 0.0f;
    optionTV.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.50];
    [self.view addSubview:optionTV];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        trafficBT.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-200, 0);
        optionTV.alpha = 0.8;
    }];
```

for delegate method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"tableView Data num row: %d", [optionArray count]);
    return [optionArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    if (kIsIPhone) {
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [optionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```